# System.InvalidOperationException when attempting to serialize with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, exception, serialization

I'm getting this error when trying to serialize an object in C#

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: There was an error reflecting type
>   'ComboGen.ElementLocation'.

What I'm trying to do is serialize all the control elements in a form so I can read them back in and repopulate the form.

My class that I want to serialize and holds the control elements is defined like

```
[System.Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(ElementLocation))]
public class ElementLocation
{
    public List<ElementLocation> subElements;
    public TextBox ActionName;
    public TextBox CoolDown;
    public TextBox ClearInputBuffer;
    public Button AddCombo;
}
```

To serialize it I'm using

```
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(myStream);
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ElementLocation));

                foreach (ElementLocation elemLoc in elementLocations)
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, elemLoc);
                }
                myStream.Close();
```

But it throws an exception when trying to call Serialize. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: All properties in your class must be serializable too, is the `ElementLocation` serializable too, the same for the `Control` class ?

Comment: Doesn't adding [System.Serializable] to the start of the class make is serializable? I realized Control was an ADT so I tried switched to using the derived classes, but I get the same error.

Comment: Yes adding [System.Serializable] annotation before the class declaration to make it serializable,  What do you mean by ADT?

Comment: ADT means abstract data type. They are classes that can't be instantiated like an abstract class or interface. I thought Control was one, but it looks like it isn't.

Comment: are you trying to serialize the System.Windows.Controls.Control class? or Control is your defined class?

Comment: for the first case, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116354/how-to-serialize-controls